# Is there a unit of measure for computational complexity; through quantum computers?

Tags: computational-physics, complexity

I'm concerned with trying to determine whether the same computational processes on a Turing computable algorithm can be ascertained for a quantum computer in some form of actual 'metric' for how many resources are utilized by the computer?

Is this possible to translate the same complexity to the lowest common denominator of a traditional computer, but instead, for a quantum computer and then be able to determine a universal metric for computability?

Comment: This seems more a question related to Computer science than Computational Science.

Answer (score 2):

The quantum equivalent of how many bits you need to store is the number of "qubits" are required for a certain computation. The quantum equivalent of the number of operations is the number of "gates" that need to be applied.